# Unable to subtract from a number in LISP?

Tags: function, types, lisp, common-lisp

So I'm implementing a function that gets the first n elements of a list in LISP (Allegro mlisp) for a project and I can't seem to figure out why I can't do the subtraction calculation. I keep getting

My code for this method is, which compiles in the listener fine

```
(defun get_upto (n cut_list)
(if (= n 0) cut_list 
    (cons (car cut_list) (get_upto ((- n 1) (cdr cut_list))))))
```

but if I try to execute

`$: (get_upto 3 '(1 2 3 4 5))`

I get the error

`Error: Illegal function object: (- n 1)`

What am I doing wrong here? I'm passing in a number and it has no problem checking if n = 0.

Comment: there is a parenthesis to many in the last line that why it thinks you want to use (- n 1) as function.

Comment: and you might want to change your exit statement to `(= n 0) nil`

Comment: Common Lisp requires you to get your parentheses correct. This is different from other languages you might be used to. Parentheses change the meaning of your program. They are never optional or meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many parens!

This is "subtract 1 from n, and pass the result as the first argument to `get_upto`"

```
(get_upto (- n 1) (cdr cut_list))
```

But you have this:

```
(get_upto ((- n 1) (cdr cut_list)))
```

which is "subtract 1 from n and use the result of that calculation as a function whose first argument is `(cdr cut_list)`"

Comment: Thanks! Just like OCaml, its the small things in LISP that get me now and then!